# Razor Script Intermittent Errors

Tags: razor

Having trouble with Razor Script Errors happening periodically.
Try to stack trace ,once you click "Debug & Trace" error disappears and page loads without any problem. so don't know why its happening.
I am using umbraco as CMS, C# in Visual Studio 2010. Sql Server 2010 for data storage.
I searched everywhere, find one answer on this problem, but that did not help in my case.
This is my first question Guys on Stack Overflow. I know i always find solution on stack overflow for my problems, some body will help me with this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

what version of Umbraco? I had the race condition problem with MediaById in Razor on 4.9.1 ala http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/35345-ModelMediaById-gives-error-Error-loading-MacroEngine-script-(file-)
short term fix = recycle app pool
long term fix - upgrade to 4.11.7+